# What is a distance or similarity metric that takes into account the improbability of a match?

Tags: machine-learning, distance-functions, recommender-system

Suppose I want to measure similarity between users. If two users match on an item that is very improbable, I want to give greater weight to that.

Comment: Almost _any_ (dis)similarity measure can be in its weighted version. Just insert weight into its formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weight the item with the inverse of all occurrences of this item. If you treat a user as a document and an item as a term this is the equivalent to calculate the [inverse document frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%2aidf) (idf).

If you transform your user vectors like that and calculate the cosine or some any other similarity afterwards, then items which occur less (and hence have more differentiation power) gain a higher weight.